# Can't install Tensorflow on Fedora

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, fedora

I'm using Fedora and I installed tensorflow successfully before but today I tried to use it and it's not there so used `pip -m install tensorflow` but I'm getting this error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.12.0 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.12.0`

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: it's python 3.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tensorflow` is not available for python `3.12` yet as of January 2, 2024.

**https://www.tensorflow.org/install**

> Python 3.8–3.11

Comment: Ok, what do I do?

Comment: Please use `python 3.11` until it is available on `3.12`.